# MySQLi class update using DATE_ADD in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am running this query in phpmyadmin and mysqli() and it update records properly. But on running it in `joshcam's MySQLi Database class` it updates wrong data.

Query:

```
UPDATE table SET `status` = 0 WHERE   time <= DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MINUTE )
```

PHP Code:

```
$db->where('time', 'DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MINUTE )', '<=');
$db->update( 'table', array('status'=> '0') );
```

Also Tried:

```
$db->where('time', $db->now('-2m'), '<=');
$db->update( 'table', array('status'=> '0') );
```

Is there anything wrong in MySQLi class query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET status = 0 WHERE time <= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE )
```